# How to get current git branch name in ZSH?

Tags: git, zsh, oh-my-zsh

can anybody help me, How can I show the current git branch name in my `zsh`? I tried to use `oh my zsh`, but still doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bzsh%5D+current+branch

Comment: Run `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`